# Examples of "interesting" applications of that fact that $ACF_p$ is $\kappa$-categorical?

Tags: abstract-algebra, first-order-logic, model-theory

In my Mathematical Logic course, we have discussed the fact that $ACF_p$ (algebraically closed fields of characteristic $p$) is is $\kappa$-categorical for $\kappa > \aleph_0$ in FO logic. I can see how this can be very useful in the field of pure algebra since it implies completeness of the theory- if I prove something FO for $\mathbb{C}$, I've proven it for $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$! However, although using the completeness "feels" very interesting, it simultaneously feels verey restricted, since I can't even discuss "polynomials" in general within FO logic. My question is whether anyone has any non-trivial examples of FO statements that, say, can be proven $\mathbb{C}$ and thus hold for all $ACF_0$ fields (or a phenomenon of similar nature)?

Comment: Not exactly what you asked about, but something you would almost certainly be interested in, is the model theoretic proof of the [Ax-Grothendieck Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ax%E2%80%93Grothendieck_theorem), which says that polynomials from $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ which are injective are automatically surjective. This is more or less because the result is true in finite fields, and we cleverly transfer the result by a combination of the Nullstellensatz and the relation between $\mathsf{ACF}_0$ and $\mathsf{ACF}_p$.

Comment: You might also find the Lefschetz principle from algebraic geometry interesting, it's a more general and less formal version of this idea

Comment: The problem is that part of the *reason* that $ACF_0$ is complete in the first place is that there's very little going on, first-order-definably, in an algebraically closed field. (I'm referring to *quantifier elimination* here.)